# How to achieve multi-tier versioning avoidance?

Tags: web-services, database-design, microservices

First of all, sorry for the vague or maybe even confusing title. If I knew how to brief my question more precisely, probably I've already found the answer. :-(

Here is my problem, we provide our software capabilities via web/micro services and the customers develop their own client apps to consume our services. When we make a breaking change to a service, ideally we would like to provide another version of the service and leave the old version as is so that a customer won't be forced to upgrade their tools.

However sometimes a breaking change on the service is backed by a breaking change on the database. The changed database schema can't support both old and new versions of the service. And sometimes we can't simply attach a interpreting step behind the old version to fill the gap such as in the case where a new mandatory field is required with no good default value if the client doesn't provide it.

So because of this difficulty, we now have to discontinue the old version when we release a new version service. And certainly the customers have to upgrade their tools as well, which unfortunately reduce the satisfaction level.

Any good solutions please? Thanks.

Comment: Beyond letting them know as early as possible that you are going to be making those changes, not much is possible - unless there is the possibility of hosting multiple versions of the database in production as well.

Comment: Define "breaking change". If your changes are additive and don't affect existing schema, existing clients should be immune and safe. Requiring new mandatory fields without a default value is really harsh, and you should strongly consider relaxing that requirement.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using clear version definitions for your APIs so expectations are clearly set. Semantic Versioning is a good starting point: http://semver.org/

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, especially @BrianKelly. Your comment really woke me up as there is no way to introduce a breaking change like a new mandatory field  but still can migrate the existing database without any user actions, unless a suitable default value can be found. But if a default value exists, then I reckon the change is not breaking.